# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory changes according to the app's target platform

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this path set up as the path to the root dir of the application.
It worked perfectly until I decided to change my `System.Data.SQLite.dll` lib and my application to 32bit instead of 64bit (which I initially changed to because I downloaded the 64bit version of the sqlite lib.

`private string fullPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "testdb.db");`

The problem is that on launch, there is an error saying that the `access to "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/IDE/test.db" is denied`, which means that somehow `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` references to that directory instead of my application's root directory.

What could be the cause of this?

**Update**:
Apparently, changing the applications platform target to x64, and using the 64b version of SQLite fixes the problem...

Comment: Did you tried to debug the application? Inner exception?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you started the application in debug mode hosted in Visual Studio by hitting F5!